Number of days by Month from a date range
PowerBI report required for leave by employee. Dates are by range only ie Start and End of leave dates. When date ranges cross months I cant determine how many days belong to each month. Ideally I would only look at Weekdays not weekends
How can I report the number of days of leave taken per month ie split the date range into months?
I think I need to expand the rows into single days and then sum



ID Staff
Leave
Type
Start Date
End Date
Days Taken




1000675
Annual
Leave
27/12/24
17/01/25
16.00


2302135
Annual
Leave
23/12/24
10/01/25
13.00


2303149
Annual
Leave
27/12/24
8/01/25
9.00


1000812
Annual
Leave
20/12/24
7/01/25
11.00


1000275
Annual
Leave
24/12/24
6/01/25
6.00


1000769
Annual
Leave
23/12/24
3/01/25
8.00


2304494
Annual
Leave
23/12/24
3/01/25
8.00


1176278
Annual
Leave
16/12/24
3/01/25
13.00


1000379
Annual
Leave
24/12/24
1/01/25
5.00


1405149
Annual
Leave
23/12/24
1/01/25
6.00


1000477
Annual
Leave
9/12/24
1/01/25
15.00


1000081
Annual
Leave
31/12/24
31/12/24
0.45


1000517
Annual
Leave
30/12/24
31/12/24
2.00


1000662
Annual
Leave
30/12/24
31/12/24
2.00


2300641
Annual
Leave
27/12/24
31/12/24
3.00


1000594
Annual
Leave
27/12/24
31/12/24
3.00


1000757
Annual
Leave
27/12/24
31/12/24
3.00


1000755
Annual
Leave
27/12/24
31/12/24
3.00




This question is similar to: How do I create a column in PowerBI that displays the count of a specific value. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you can split the date to rows in PQ
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("ldM7DoMwDAbgu2RGxa/YMHbvDRADA1vF1p6/YWjiqka0Ex745N+JM00JAUAtpy5dt+2x3EtxW5fnWr5kPVJPUkq0HrCn/TfUC0CauykRAyHHlBuFRtlRRhlPug5Vjm+4xx2QQggVurToJR0MKlVqleqhaZy1jckVDm5IkVH+h4imZEMEUQPYznXPyhZnbUNilblCgXx0IRzAj9MRswiOgcPsYbnKCDK2IVsJF8lVZgxbMkSSfE/VcHtOZLlLUAnTuoX1wX3PfLAF59JyOOdP8uxRf8n5BQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"D Staff" = _t, Leave = _t, Type = _t, #"Start Date" = _t, #"End Date" = _t, #"Days Taken" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Start Date", type date}}, "en-AU"),
    #"Changed Type with Locale1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type with Locale", {{"End Date", type date}}, "en-AU"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type with Locale1", "Date", each {Number.From([Start Date])..Number.From([End Date])}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Date"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom.1", each Date.DayOfWeek([Date])),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([Custom.1] <> 5 and [Custom.1] <> 6))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"


then use DAX to create a date table
date =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDAR ( MIN ( 'Table'[Start Date] ), MAX ( 'Table'[End Date] ) ),
    "month", MONTH ( [Date] )
)

create relationship between tables
then you can get the leave days for each month

